# How to sort row data from Android sqlite database for a particular year in date field

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am having below table on my android sqlite database.

My Date filed is TEXT;

```
ID   Name   Date 
1    ABY    2014-12-01
2    RUBY   2015-01-10
3    AMY    2015-01-15
4    ROBEN  2014-10-25
```

I need to sort the result like in mysql

```
select * from Table where YEAR(DATE)='2015';
```

How can I get the above result in Andorid sqlite database?

Comment: Is your Date is in  DATETIME DataType ?

Comment: Sort has nothing to do with where. **Where** used for filter. while **Order By** is used to sort. Now what do u need? Sort or filter

Comment: I am trying to filter the result, can you please comment the android query method or rawquery to get the result.

Comment: Well. AFAIK sqlite has no date as data type. So try the answer below by chris. It might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the LIKE operand

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date LIKE '2015%'

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm

Edit for query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE date like \'" + "2015" + "\'";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { fileNameOfDb });
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
}
c.close();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to execute the above statement via query in andorid, Like...db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID,
,KEY_NAME},(("%Y",KEY_DATE) + "=" + "2015"), null,
                        null, null, null, null);

Comment: String selectQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE date like \'" + "2015" + "\'";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { fileNameOfDb });
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
}
c.close();